How to debug PHP running in local docker container with VSC?
Context
I have a problem with my PHP website. To solve it, I want to step through the code. I am on a Windows machine using VSC as IDE. PHP runs in a docker container in parallel to an nginx container.
The Problem
I don't know how to connect my VSC Debugger with the PHP runtime in the docker container.
I installed/enabled Xdebug and added a launch.json but the VSC Debugger does not react on page requests.
More details on what I tried
Xdebug seems to work. At least php -v (in the php container) returns
PHP 8.2.26 (cli) (built: Nov 21 2024 17:59:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.26, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

My xdebug.ini config is:
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal

My launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Local docker Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "hostname": "localhost",
      "port": 9003,
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/amc/plattform": "${workspaceFolder}\\amc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I then run 'Local docker Xdebug' and can see that the port is listening.
When I do a request, the page comes up, but the debugger does not connect/stop.
Any idea what is missing?
Update
Thanks to the great comments below I added a page with xdebug_info(); and enabled xdebug logging.
I get:
[Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

So my container can't connect to the host port. This is not the first time I want a container to connect to a host port. I am even doing this successfully in another container of the same docker compose file.
Inspired by this SO answer I added
 extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

Still not lucky.
I don't think that this is the way to go but I also tried to add 9003:9003 to the published ports of the container. I was surprised as the error was gone. Unfortunately VSC still did not react.
The info page showed
Debugger            Active  
Connected Client    host.docker.internal:9003

Looked positiv, but this is independant of the VSC Debugger. So if the Debugger is not listening, the info page still tells me "Debugger: Active" (I guess because my docker port publishing opens that port to pipe it into the container). Seems like xdebug only checks for the open port and not if a real debgger is listening on the other end.
The xdebug.log shows
[7] Log opened at 2024-12-02 22:04:21.868029
[7] [Config] WARN: Not setting up control socket with default value due to unavailable 'tsc' clock
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[7] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/amc/plattform/public_html/phpinfo-192837465.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.2.26" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7"><engine version="3.4.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2024 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[7] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
[7] Log closed at 2024-12-02 22:04:21.893973

Any ideas left what I can try?

You need to add Path Mappings to your launch.json. It's a little old, but review this article to walk you through.

Thanks a lot for your comment and the link! This article is a perfect fit, unfortunately it did not help yet (I have added the pathMappings, also in the question above, but the behavior is still the same).

Is there a way to make xdebug log problems with the connection?

Have you've exposed the XDebug Port in the Docker configuration file, so your VSC can connent to the XDebug inside the Docker?

@andymel: 1. try debugging a script with xdebug_info() in it, it will give you Diagnostics. Otherwise, use xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log and xdebug.log_level=11 and it will be full of useful information. As a hunch, you need to change \\ to / in your path mapping before amc.

@Derick: thanks a lot for those great tips. Please have a look at my 'Updated' chapter! While I have more insights now I am still stuggling.

@Anuga: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't think this is the right path as xdebug connects to VSC and not the other way around. So I don't want to expose the container port to the host but the host port to the container. I still tried! Please see my Updated chapter above for the details. Also, after publishing 9003:9003 in the docker container config, VSC can not start the debugger anymore, as 9003 is already in use by docker.

Solved it! ...currently writing an answer.

The VSC debugger port was listening on the loopback interface (tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1).
I analyzed the difference to another container->host connection in the same docker compose and found, that the connection that worked, listened on 0.0.0.0:port (0.0.0.0 means listen on all network interfaces).
After simply removing the "hostname" parameter from my launch.json, xdebug was able to connect.
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Local docker Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      // "hostname": "localhost",   <= without this, the debugger listens on 0.0.0.0
      "port": 9003,
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/amc/plattform": "${workspaceFolder}/amc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

